# How to set a monitor to get the runtime message of a Java application

Tags: java, monitoring, monitor

There is a Java application to be tested. Are there some ways to set a monitor to get which functions are executed?
Or are there some ways to set reflections to get some message of the application?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways:

- Use code coverage tools which would generate a report of all executed methods / lines / branches.

  - jacoco [www.jacoco.org]
  - cobertura [cobertura.github.io/cobertura]
  - clover [www.atlassian.com/software/clover]
  - jcov [wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/CodeTools/jcov]
- Implement Java Instrumentation Agent. The following blog posts shows how to calculate method execution time. It should be trivial task to modify it for your needs.

  - http://blog.javabenchmark.org/2013/05/java-instrumentation-tutorial.html
  - http://javapapers.com/core-java/java-instrumentation